# Cannot deserialize instance of datetime from VALUE_STRING value

Tags: workbench, post

I have a REST webservice which inserts multiple records into custom objects. I am executing it on workbench using the following request:

{"req" : {"tickets": [{
"External_TicketID__c" :1853,
"Date_Time__c": "9/13/2015 20:30"
},
{
"External_TicketID__c" :26554,
"Date_Time__c": "9/13/2015 22:30"
}
]}}

I am getting the following JSON Parse error.What am I doing wrong?

message: Cannot deserialize instance of datetime from VALUE_STRING value 9/13/2015 02:30 AM at [line:3, column:37]
 errorCode: JSON_PARSER_ERROR

Comment: Did you try passing in this format 2007-04-05T12:30-02:00 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the field is a date-time field, you've the wrong format. It should be in standard ISO 8601 format:

```
{"req" : {"tickets": [{ "External_TicketID__c" :1853, "Date_Time__c": "2015-09-13T20:30:00.000Z" }, { "External_TicketID__c" :26554, "Date_Time__c": "2015-09-13T22:30:00.000Z" } ]}}
```

As a side note, make sure that External_TicketID__c is indeed a number field, or you'll get an error there, too.

Comment: I just tried deserializing a JSON string with the exact same format you have above. I received the following error: System.JSONException: Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value 2016-12-05T16:19:44.000Z..... Check out the DateTime format: 2016-12-05T16:19:44.000Z - what's off?

Comment: @ZAR I know this is years old at this point but in case anyone else comes across this, your error seems to point to `date` not `datetime`. In other words, you would need to cut off the time part in the string or convert the field to a datetime field.

Comment: @MatthewGreen good catch! I've been waiting 2,477 days for an answer! I can finally go home!