# JSON: Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING

Tags: json, exception, datetime

I'm officially breaking up with Salesforce Date parsing. This has got to be the most frustrating thing.

I have the following date in a JSON string (full JSON below):

> 2017-06-03T10:34:24.000Z

But when I try to deserialize the data:

```
Opportunity[] results = (List<Opportunity>)JSON.deserialize(res, List<Opportunity>.class);
```

I get the following error:

> System.JSONException: Cannot deserialize instance of date from VALUE_STRING value 2016-12-05T16:19:44.000Z

I have looked at so many date parse issues before and from what I've gathered  it must be in ISO 8601 - though ISO 8601 can take various shapes: [Ruby Docs: ISO 8601](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime)

All of the following seem to recommend exactly what I've done

[Cannot deserialize instance of datetime from VALUE_STRING value](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/108896/cannot-deserialize-instance-of-datetime-from-value-string-value)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009BsqIAE

https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/22

https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom/issues/35

How should I format this date string?

Thank you!

Full JSON string:

```
[{
  "name":"OpportunityABC",
  "CloseDate":"2017-06-03T10:34:24.000Z",
  "StageName":"Pre-Engagement",
  "Amount":"4810308.0",
}]
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Three problems here:

(a) Date receiving DateTime value.

The value should be "YYYY-MM-DD" only.

(b) Decimal receiving String value.

The value should not be in quotes.

(c) You must not have a trailing comma.

JSON-compliant strings are more strict than normal JavaScript.

```
[{
  "name":"OpportunityABC",
  "CloseDate":"2017-06-03",
  "StageName":"Pre-Engagement",
  "Amount":4810308.0
}]
```

Comment: Making the change to Date instead of DateTime fixed it. Thanks man!